# Chef Knife not saving changes with editor

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe, chef-solo, knife

I want to create a role with knife. So I run:

```
> knife role create beautifulprayer
ERROR: RuntimeError: Please set EDITOR environment variable
```

No problem! Just add the editor. Afterwards:

```
> knife role create beautifulprayer
```

This opens the editor that I have set (subl) and goes ahead once the editor is open and propagates the call to the chef server, resulting in `Created role[beautifulprayer]` although the editor is still open and I have not saved anything. This happens with editing too where it results to `Object unchanged, not saving` while the editor is still open and no save happened.

This does NOT happen though when I use vim because knife waits for me to close VIM and then propogates the call to chef server. I'd like to use sublime but this isn't currently working because any changes and saving with sublime are not propagated or detected by knife.

Comment: That's unclear, what changes are not persisted ? The role has been created, where's the problem, show what you get and what you expect so we can have a clue of what your problem is.

Comment: @Tensibai I made changes to the question for more clarification

Comment: I think sublime does not respect/understand the temp file knife gives it on launch. Does it ask you where to save when finishing the edit ?

Comment: it does not. It may indeed not respect/understand it. Neither does atom either.

Comment: @Tensibai any idea for a solution?

Comment: Out of using vim, you can create your role as files and then upload them to the server with `knife role from file` as stated [here](https://docs.chef.io/knife_role.html#from-file)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to call your editor to "block" the current process and **not** fork another one. Usually this is somewhat described as "no fork", "foreground" or "wait" option:

Examples:

Sublime Text

```
export EDITOR="subl -w"
```

Atom:

```
export EDITOR="atom -f"
```

MacVim:

```
export EDITOR="mvim -f"
```

TextMate 2:

```
export EDITOR="mate -w"
```

When you've done your change, you need to close the editor and knife will pick up the change.

Comment: You're a boss! @Roland